# How to send HTTP requests to the v8 debugger?

Tags: node.js, debugging, protocols, v8, javascript-debugger

The V8 javascript engine implements [this](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol) debugger protocol. I start V8 (node.js) and I can connect through the browser to the open port (5858). What is the format of a request that needs to be send to the V8 debugger? Is is a GET or POST?

The only thing that the mentioned page says is: "each packet [...] is transmitted as a string value"

Give me please one example request made one of: curl, node.js, or the browser.

Comment: the specification of the v8 debugger protocol is in v8/src/d8.js.
You can view its source online, [click here, d8.js](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/d8.js?r=12566)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened this issue [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5512) to ask for help, maybe the joyent guys can spot the mistake in what I am trying to do. I will update this answer when I "get a valid response" (either from joyent or from the debugger ;) )

EDIT: I have also asked this on the node mailing list and received [this relevant answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nodejs/h6lYK3i6KTA)

Summary: don't expect standard (restless) HTTP request-response behavior. You would have to send/test the request using other tools (`node-request`/`telnet`). This is because the V8 debugger leaves the connection open and sends multiple responses over it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) as a sample.

The relevant files should be in https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/tree/master/lib

---

The debugger does not use HTTP. I don't know curl but you need to send your Content-length and JSON without any HTTP headers.

Comment: This is a good idea still not the answer. I've looked into it: it opens a connection and sends a `Content-Length` header then the content. When I try to do (almost) the same with `curl` the debugger does not respond.